# How to properly retarget stdlib's `FILE` functions `fread`, `fwrite`, `fseek`, etc. to custom FileSystem driver?

Tags: c++, c, stdio

I am writing firmware for embedded device with ARM chip. 
Firmware contains FatFS, and several peripherals which wanted to make accessible via C `<stdio.h>` and C++ `<iostream>` interfaces. 
So, I need to implement std-compatible functions for every driver. OK. Done. Next I need **somehow** to map *stdlib*'s `fxxxx` functions to mine `fatfs_fread()`, `fatfs_fwrite()`, `uart_fopen()`, ...
How to connect my code to stdlib portably?

#### My way

1. Implement std-to-custom-driver bridge functions. I.e. `fatfs_fread()`, `fatfs_fwrite()`, `uart_fopen()`, ...
2. Redefine `struct FILE {}`
3. Redefine/retarget `fopen()`, `fread()`, `fwrite`, `fxxxxx()`

*Pseudocode of idea*.

`struct FILE` should contain pointers to all possible stdlib `fxxxx` functions:

```
struct FILE {
    void* handle_;
    FILE* (*fopen)(const char* filenname, const char *mode );
    *fread ;
    *fwrite;
    *fclose;
    ...
};
```

`fxxxx()` calls proper function on `FILE` if exist.

```
size_t fwrite( 
            const void *restrict buffer, 
            size_t size, 
            size_t count,
            FILE *restrict stream )
{
    if( stream->fwrite )
        return stream->fwrite(buffer,size,count,stream);
    return 0;
}
```

`fopen()` creates an instance of `FILE` and fills it with proper function pointers:

```
FILE * fopen(const char *path, mode){
    // Fill struct depending on file path, and call its xxxx_fopen()
    if( path begins with MASK_UART ){
        return uart_fopen(path,mode);
    }else if( path begins with MASK_FatFS )
        ;
    else
        return NULL;
}
```

Comment: This is most certainly platform specific, you should indicate, by a tag, which one it is (Windows, Linux, ...).

Comment: This is not C++. Don't tag both C and C++.

Comment: Using [tag:gcc] you could use `-fno-builtin-function` option. Take a look at [The Man](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.2.2/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html)

Comment: What's in your `stdlib` that you mention? How does it work at a low level?  How is all your C and/or C++ code for this platform compiled?  Your method is effectively a reimplementation of the *entire* stdio-based set of functions.  Are you sure that's an O&M commitment you're prepared to sign up for?  And that's just for C `stdio` functionality.  C++ `iostream`-based functionality is going to be an even larger commitment.

Comment: This is going to have a crazy wild amount of UB.

Comment: @Christian.K, this is mostly for embedded platforms with RTOS, but I'd like to keep portability - embedded program have to be able to be compiled on host system like linux or windows.